# Should I follow up on job interview when HR said they will update on my hiring 2 weeks ago

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, human-resources, follow-up

I have completed two job interviews.

One company emailed me 2 weeks ago telling that I'm shortlisted for hiring, and even the manager sent me a message personally, whether I have received an offer letter and asked me to wait for HR to do a background check (since I mention I haven't heard any update from HR). Should I follow up on HR again since the last time that I email them is after HR said that I'm shortlisted for hiring (before manager sent me the message) or should I wait for 1 week more? Another one asked me to email my document since he didn't take my hard copy even though in job invitation clearly ask me to bring those. It has been 5 days since the interview happens (including weekends). Should I email the document now and ask for follow up (I really like the job and the manager)? Is it okay for a candidate to keep bother the hiring company?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should follow it up. It is not like that you have that one possible offer only and in case things go south, you need to know beforehand, without wasting your time on waiting on something that is not going to happen.

Follow up with them and inquire about the progress. If you have a number that you can call, try to reach them over the call. We all need to deal a large number of emails and at times (sad but true), email communications fall through the crack.

You don't need to ask for a specific date, even a "date for a date" (i.e., letting you know by when they would get back to you with a specific part - offer, verification check initiation, any additional process etc.) would be okay but waiting for it with an indefinite deadline is not the way to go.

Your time is as precious as your potential employer's.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer